# How to dialogue with an SSO service and open URL

Tags: c#, .net, http

I'm a JS/jQuery developer who's dipping his toe for the first time in the C#/.NET world with a new web service.

There's an external SSO service that I need to communicate with. I send it a URL with some query string parameters, it replies with a URL that includes an SSO token, then I need to pop that URL into the end user's browser.

Any pointers on how to do this with C#?

Some additional info... I'm trying to modify some existing code that sort of did something similar using System.Net.HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse and an HTML form with hidden inputs, but I'm a bit lost trying to make sense of what the code is doing, and anyway it uses a form with POST, whereas the SSO service I'm connecting to just uses query string parameters.

Comment: What type of project is it? Asp.net MVC? Core? Web forms?

Comment: It's for a proprietary application called Architect by Fiserv, but Architect is MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close the loop on this, I resolved it by... using JavaScript. Basically the C# code injects some JS to the page to perform the redirect. Probably not be the best way to do this, but it worked...

Comment: If you're answering your own question, then you should post your code so that it can help other people, otherwise you should [edit] your question and add the text of this answer.